# Defining interest rate array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to create a mortgage calculator on python that can cope with multiple interest rate changes.

I want it to recalculate the repayment formula every month, with a new interest rate.

What is the best way to define an array of interest rates?

Say I had a 20 year mortgage, this array would need 240 entries, which could change at any time, it seems there must be a quicker way than typing out `y=(0.01,0.01,0.01,0.015,0.015,0.02,0.015,0.02,0.02..)` etc

Comment: do you manually change it or is programmatically changed? Also, is there a relation between the monthly interest values? You need to be more specific on how the interest array is created/generated.

Comment: You can do [0.01]*240 to get list of 240 equal entries. However if you have some kind of relation, just use list comprehension: `[your_relation(i) for i in range(240)]`

Comment: That is my problem, I want it to be able to change at random points, but i do not know how to generate this. There won't be a relation with the interest rates, it will be random.

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].